VW Tiguan 2019 fan running very high and drains battery. OBD Code P0071
my car shows OBD Code P0071 and I don't know if that's the reason the fan is going crazy fast and drains the battery. When I googled, there were suggestions about the relay but given the OBD Code P0071, I was wondering if that's the issue and not the relay. Could someone help me out?
Edit: No engine light is on

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Do you know if your cooling fan has several speeds? P0071 is for the ambient air temperature sensor. A resistance check with a multimeter can verify it; or cold water raises resistance, heat lowers resistance.
